# Image Loader "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null"

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I pass my view imageview into this imageloader class I have created, but for some reason I am getting this error "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null" which seems to only happen for some images, that the url's should be fine with. It will only load 3 out of a list of ten. I was wondering if this task wasn't properly thread safe or something else I may have missed. Take a look below

**ImageLoader:**

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.failed_load;

    public void displayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        System.out.println(url);

        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }

    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null) {
            return b;
        }

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(3000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            IOUtils.copy(is, os);// Util.CopyStream(is, os); //TODO DELETE
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            // TODO Can change image content here.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 512;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
                return;
            }
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
                return;
            }
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
                return;
            }
            if (bitmap != null) {
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Same problem for me also, where need to check???

Comment: Check your actual web urls and make sure they are proper.

Comment: Yes everything is proper, i cant load https url in my android application, except that everything ok. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the solution was double checking the incoming url's, that were wrong, and everything seems to be fine now. For anyone else having a similar problem, double check what you are loading, and the files that are coming in, from wherever you are trying to load them.